# Javascript: Bug when matching filetypes?

Tags: javascript, file-type

I was working on a little script today, and ran into a bug that I can't seem to fix (or locate properly in the first place.)

This is basically the important part of the script:

```
function handleFiles(files,e) {
    var imageType = /image.*/;  
    var file = files[0];
    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {  
      return false; 
    }  
}
```

When trying to use it, it won't work at all.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of the dot?

Answer (score 3):

`.` has a special meaning in RegExp (any character). If you want to detect a dot, you need to escape it like this:

```
var imageType = /image\.*/;
```